# For loop is running too often

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop

I have a for loop which should run 4 times but is running 6 times.
Could you please explain the behaviour?
This is strange because stringarr1 is not changed.

Edit: I want to remove all '!' from my first string and want to save the letters in a second string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char stringarr1[] = "a!bc";
  char stringarr2[] = "";

  printf("%d\n", strlen(stringarr1));  // lenght --> 4

  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(stringarr1); i++)  
  {
      printf("i: %d\n", i);
      if (stringarr1[i] != '!') {
        stringarr2[strlen(stringarr2)] = stringarr1[i];
        printf("info: != '!'\n");
      }          
  }
}
```

Comment: `char stringarr2[] = "";` this makes an array of size 1, and `stringarr2[0]` is the null terminator. You can't do string manipulation this way. Give it a proper size.

Comment: What makes come to your conclusion?

Comment: before i even look at anything else, do not use strlen in the conditional of the for loop. it counts the string length every loop iteration. store the length in a variable before the loop.

Comment: When you loop iterates, i = 0, stringarr2[0] = 'a', when i = 1, it will do nothing, stringarr2 has a length of 1, when i = 2, stringarr2 will contain ab, when i = 3, stringarr2 will contain abc.  No obvious error.  Doh!  As already posted by Blaze, stringarr2 has no size.  Correct with char stringarr2[sizeof(stringarr1)]

Comment: this code seems to have deeper problems. You are only taking characters other than `'!'` so do you want to leave gaps where the `'!'` is or do you want to append the other characters and not leave a gap? Leaving a gap means you need to choose a specific character to put in the gap. Appending means you need to keep a separate iterator in your loop for the 2nd string. Either way like everyone else said you need to allocate the 2nd string to a large enough size.

Comment: I want to remove all '!' !

Comment: @ChrisRollins There are no gaps as the character is copied to the end of the string. Wherever this might be....

Comment: I can not understand the close vote. Can somebody explain this? I mean it is specific right?

Comment: As a side note, printing the return value of `strlen()`, which is of type `size_t`, using `printf()` with `%d` (which expects `int`) leads to undefined behavior. Use `%zu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overrunning the buffer for `stringarr2` (length 1), which is *in this case* corrupting the memory-adjacent `stringarr1`, causing the string length to change by overwriting its nul terminator.

Then because you are reevaluating the string length on each iteration, the loop will run for a non-deterministic number of iterations - in your case just 6, but it could be worse; the behaviour you have observed is just one of several possibilities - it is *undefined*.

Apart from correcting the buffer length for `stringarr2`, it is best practice to evaluate loop-invariants once (although in this case the string length is not invariant due to a bug).  So the following:

```
  const size_t length = strlen( stringarr1 ) ;
  for( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++ )
  {
      ...
```

will run for 4 iterations regardless of the buffer overrun bug because the length is not reevaluated following the corruption. Re-evaluating loop-invariants can lead to very slow code execution.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can run any number of times. You write beyond the end of `stringarr2` so you may be smashing the stack and overwriting local variables. What you meant to do is probably something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

  char stringarr1[] = "a!bc";
  char stringarr2[10];
  int len = strlen(stringarr1);

  printf("%d\n", len);  // lenght --> 4

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)  
  {
      printf("i: %d\n", i);
      if (stringarr1[i] != '!') {
        stringarr2[len] = stringarr1[i];
        printf("info: != '!'\n");
      }          
  }
}
```

Like others said, it is not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here. But in C, a declaration like `char s[] = "string"` only allocates enough memory to store whatever is on the right hand side of the assignment. If that is an empty string like in your case, only a single byte is allocated, to store the end of string 'null' character. You need to either explicitly specify, like I did, the number of bytes to allocate as the array size, or use dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're writing past the end of `stringarr2`.  This triggers [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To fix this, you need to allocate sufficient memory for `stringarr2`.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must allocate the string to be long enough.

```
char stringarr1[] = "a!bc";

//save this in a variable beforehand because strlen loops over the string every time it is called
size_t len = strlen(stringarr1);  

char stringarr2[1024] = { 0 };
```

{ 0 } initializes all characters in the string to 0, which means the last one will always be a null terminator after we add characters. This tells C string functions where the string ends.

Now we can put stuff in there. It seems like you're trying to append, so keep a separate iterator for the 2nd string. This is more efficient than calling strlen every loop.

```
for(size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++){
  printf("i: %d\n", i);
  if (stringarr1[i] != '!') {
    stringarr2[j++] = stringarr1[i];
    printf("info: != '!'\n");
  } 
}
```